# MFC: How to save the position of toolbars in the legacy MFC ver 6?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, toolbar, state

I have a striking question: **How to save the position of toolbars in the legacy MFC ver 6?**

I can't use `CWinApp::SaveBarState` because not all toolbars exist at the moment this function would be called (causing it to assert). Instead, I instantiate the toolbars depending on what kind of document is loaded.
I unfortunately yet didn't find my way with `CToolBarCtrl::SaveState` which would be ideal to use, I guess. However, when playing with it, I'm experiencing two problems:

- (a) It strangely saves the toolbar so that when restored, it has no buttons (and just minimal dimensions, which implies from the no-buttons fact).
- (b) When I place two toolbars next to each other and close the application, they show up below each other when restored (which is what I want to avoid). I understand that this may be the result of wrongly saving the state, just as described in (a).

Any helping hand appreciated, many thanks!

Regards,

Tomas

Answer (score 1):

Before switching to the ribbon, I used this funcion from [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160/Docking-Toolbars-Side-By-Side) to arrange my toolbars:

```
void CMainFrame::DockControlBarLeftOf(CToolBar* Bar, CToolBar* LeftOf)
{
    CRect rect;
    DWORD dw;
    UINT n;

    // get MFC to adjust the dimensions of all docked ToolBars
    // so that GetWindowRect will be accurate
    RecalcLayout(TRUE);

    LeftOf->GetWindowRect(&rect);
    rect.OffsetRect(1,0);
    dw=LeftOf->GetBarStyle();
    n = 0;
    n = (dw&CBRS_ALIGN_TOP) ? AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_TOP : n;
    n = (dw&CBRS_ALIGN_BOTTOM && n==0) ? AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_BOTTOM : n;
    n = (dw&CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT && n==0) ? AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_LEFT : n;
    n = (dw&CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT && n==0) ? AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_RIGHT : n;

    // When we take the default parameters on rect, DockControlBar will dock
    // each Toolbar on a seperate line. By calculating a rectangle, we
    // are simulating a Toolbar being dragged to that location and docked.
    DockControlBar(Bar,n,&rect);
}
```

I'm sure, you can use this easily for your save and load code to restore toolbars.

Comment: Hi Thomiel, yes I though placing toolbars next to each other would be near ideal so I extracted the solution from another forum. It essentially doesn't solve my problem of saving the layout across sessions (in the registry or INI file), but like I said, it's close enough. I've at least upvoted your answer ;-)